# Is it possible to create a 2nd gen package depending on a external managed package?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, second-generation-packaging

So, that's the question, can I make depending on an external managed package (i.e. an app from the app exchange) my second generation package?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. First, see [Which Package Dependencies Work with Second-Generation Managed Packages?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_dependency_overview.htm). The only real limitation here is that a 1GP cannot depend on a 2GP. Dependencies on Unlocked Packages are only "not recommended."

To actually know how do so, read [Create Dependencies Between Second-Generation Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_dependencies.htm). In summary, you just use the package and version number, like this:

```
"dependencies": [ 
   {
      "package": "OtherOrgPackage@1.2.0"
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have another question related. In "OtherOrgPackage" what is supposed I have to write? The namespace of the other package?

Comment: @FranMejias Namespaces for 2GP are not unique. If you use an alias in `sfdx-project.json`, it's the alias for the package version. You can also use the `0Ho` package ID with a version number (`0Ho000000012345@1.2.3`), or the `04t` version ID (`04t0000000ABcDE`). You can find these ID values from `sf package list` if the package is installed in an org.